# Is there a function $f(x)$ that satisfies $f(e^x) = e^x f(x)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, continuity, functional-equations

Does there exist any function $f$ such that

$$f(e^x) = e^x f(x)?$$

If so, I believe it could be used to create an analytics versions of the function $\exp_{n+1}(x) = \exp(\exp_{n}(x))$ (where $n$ is an integer and $\exp_0(x)=x$ as an initial condition; I don't know what combinations of $x$ and $n$ that would work) by letting $\exp_n(x)$ be a solution to the differential equation

$$\frac{\partial\, \exp_n(x)}{\partial\, n} = f(\exp_n(x)).$$

Comment: One can start with any function whatsoever defined on $(-\infty,0]$ and then use the desired functional equation to define it on $(0,1]$, then $(1,e]$, then $(e,e^e]$, and so on. So there are countless functions of this type. With only slightly more work one can arrange for them to be continuous, differentiable, and so on. Real analytic is another story....

Comment: To get the trivial answer out of the way: $f \equiv 0$ works.

Comment: Let $g(x) = e^x$ and let $h(x) = [f\circ g](x) = f[g(x)].$  Then, $h'(x) = f'[g(x)] \times g'(x) = f'(e^x) \times e^x.$  By the problem's premise, $h(x) = g(x) \times f(x).$  This implies that $h'(x) = [g'(x) \times f(x)] + [f'(x) \times g(x)] = e^x[f(x) + f'(x)].$  So, one solution that does **not** work is $f(x) = 1 \implies f'(x) = 0.$

Comment: Seems tough to find non-trivial solutions to $f'(e^x) = f(x) + f'(x).$

Comment: The set of solutions form a vector space: the sum of two solutions is a solution and if $f$ is a solution, then so is $\lambda f$.

Comment: This is equivalent to solving equation $F(c+1)=c F(1)$

Comment: @Anixx If $c=0$ we have $F(1)=0$ so $F(c)\equiv0$?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire this is one of the solutions, yes. This function $F$ is flow of $f$. So, it it is constant zero, $f$ is also a constant zero, it is one of the solutions pointed out above.

Comment: @Anixx If this $F(c+1)=cF(1)$ is one of the solutions then it is not "equivalent".

Comment: @TheSimpliFire sorry, I don't understand

Comment: Solving $f(x)=f(e^x)e^{-x}$ is equivalent to solving $g(x)=g(e^x)-e^x$.

Answer (score 4):

You asked about a function such that
$$ f(e^x) = e^x f(x). $$
Define the function arbitrarily for $\,x\le 0.\,$ Then define
$$ f(x) = x f(\ln x)\quad \text{ for }\quad 0 < x \le 1 $$
since we already know $\,f(x)\,$ for $\,x\le 0.\,$
Similarly, define
$$ f(x) = x f(\ln x)\quad \text{ for }\quad 1 < x \le e $$
since we already know $\,f(x)\,$ for $\,0 < x\le 1.\,$
Continuing this process, we can find the value of $\,f(x)\,$
for all real numbers such that the functional equation is satisfied.

The bounty question is

> Is there an elementary function that satisfies the functional equation?

The answer to that is that if there was, then we would already know about it.
For example, the [Elementary Functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/4) chapter of
DLMF has details about the standard elementary functions. The last is the
Lambert W function which satisfies $\,W(x)e^{W(x)}=x\,$ and
$\,W(x)=x\,e^{-W(x)}.\,$
If the requirement is that the function must be differentiable, then that can
be arranged similarly by placing constraints on the values of the function
and its derivative for negative reals.

Comment: wdym by "we would already know about it" and "mild constraints"?

Comment: @Christian Thanks for asking! I will expand my answer.